# array.includes() is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

It works for the first click, but when i click it again to unselect it, it shows me error :

> state.selectedStudents.includes is not a function. (In
>   'state.selectedStudents.includes(action.item)',
>   'state.selectedStudents.includes' is undefined)

```
import {
  SELECT
} from "../actions/postActionTypes";

const initialState = {
  students: ['Aditya', 'Rohan', 'Hello'],
  selectedStudents: []
}

const selectReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {


  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT:
      return {
        ...state,
        selectedStudents: state.selectedStudents.includes(action.item) ? state.selectedStudents.splice(state.selectedStudents.indexOf(action.item), 1) : state.selectedStudents.push(action.item)
      }
      default:
        return state;
  }

}

export default selectReducer;
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all `state.selectedStudents.includes is not a function.` means that `state.selectedStudents` is not an array. so what is it?

`.push()` doesn't return the array, it returns the length of the array after push. based on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

> Array.push() return value: The new `length` property of the object upon which the method was called.

So after the first `SELECT` action, your state chages to this:

```
state = {
  students: ['Aditya', 'Rohan', 'Hello'],
  selectedStudents: 1, // <- it's a number, not an array.
}
```

And the second time you fire `SELECT` action, `state.selectedStudents.includes(action.item)` throws and error because `state.selectedStudents` is `1` which isn't an array.

Change your switch case to this:

```
switch (action.type) {
  case SELECT:
    return {
      ...state,
      selectedStudents: state.selectedStudents.includes(action.item) ?
        state.selectedStudents.filter(student => student.id !== action.item.id) :
        [...state.selectedStudents, action.item] // <- no mutation, creates a new array.
    }
  default:
    return state;
}
```

Comment: You're still mutating the original state with `splice` here.

Comment: You're right, I was focusing on `.push()` and didn't pay attention to '.splice()`. Updated the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
state.selectedStudents.push(action.item)
```

returns the new length of the array and is not a list. so the next time you try it the type number does not have the includes method.

Answer (score 1):

You're directly mutating your state. Instead of `splice` and `push` use `filter` and array spread operator:

```
switch (action.type) {
  case SELECT:
    return {
      ...state,
      selectedStudents: state.selectedStudents.includes(action.item)
        ? state.selectedStudents.filter(
            student => student.id !== action.item.id
          )
        : [...state.selectedStudents, action.item]
    };
  default:
    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would never encourage to mutate the redux state in any case. So here is my suggestion

```js
const selectReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT: {
      let selectedStudents = [...state.selectedStudents];

      if (!_.isEmpty(selectedStudents) && selectedStudents.includes(action.item)) {
        const itemIndex = selectedStudents.indexOf(action.item);
        selectedStudents = selectedStudents.splice(itemIndex, 1);
      } else {
        selectedStudents.push(action.item);
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        selectedStudents,
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```